# css difficulties changing the width of a div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

If I go into Chrome's f12 dev tools and inspect the , I can manually lessen the width; however, I'm having trouble doing it via javascript.
My implementation is using AngularJS, and coding a directive.

The `sidebar-dropdown` class is giving me the most grief. And this line has no affect (please see inline comment below in the ELSE section of the js code):

```
    element.find('.sidebar-dropdown a').css('width', '30px');
```

Here's my sidebar html, with left nev bar and collapsible icon:

```
 <div data-cc-sidebar data-ng-controller="sidebar as vm">
    <div class="sidebar-filler"></div>
    <div class="sidebar-dropdown"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i></a></div>

    <div class="sidebar-inner">
    <div class="sidebar-widget">
    </div>

    <ul class="navi">                     
         ...
    </ul> 
   <a id="addReportLink" href="" ng-click="vm.addReportToTree(e)" title="Add Report">
        <b class="fa fa-plus-square"></b>
    </a>
    <div style="float:left;">                
        <span id="treeview" kendo-tree-view="tree"                           
            k-options="vm.treeOptions"
            k-data-source="vm.reportsTree"
            k-on-change="vm.onTreeSelect(kendoEvent)">
        </span>        
    </div>         
  </div>
</div>
```

and my Angular directive :

```
app.directive('ccSidebar', function () {
    // Opens and clsoes the sidebar menu.
    // Usage:
    //  <div data-cc-sidebar>
    // Creates:
    //  <div data-cc-sidebar class="sidebar">
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {                      
        var $sidebarInner = element.find('.sidebar-inner');            
        var $dropdownElement = element.find('.sidebar-dropdown a');
        element.addClass('sidebar');           

        $dropdownElement.addClass('dropy');     // added line = BM:
        $dropdownElement.click(dropdown);

        function dropdown(e) {
            var dropClass = 'dropy';
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$dropdownElement.hasClass(dropClass)) {    // show

                $dropdownElement.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-arrow-circle-right');
                $dropdownElement.find('i').addClass('fa fa-arrow-circle-left');
                element.find('.sidebar-filler').css('width', '230px');

                $('.sidebar-dropdown a').addClass(dropClass);
                $sidebarInner.slideDown(350);                   
                $dropdownElement.addClass(dropClass);
            } else if ($dropdownElement.hasClass(dropClass)) {  // hide
                $dropdownElement.removeClass(dropClass);
                $dropdownElement.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-arrow-circle-left');
                $dropdownElement.find('i').addClass('fa fa-arrow-circle-right');                    

                $sidebarInner.slideUp(350);

                element.find('.sidebar-filler').css('width', '30px');   

                 // THESE TWO LINES HAVE NO AFFECT !!! 
                element.find('.sidebar a').css('width', '30px');
                element.find('.sidebar-dropdown a').css('width', '30px');

            }                
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you may need to set the display of the `<a>` tag to block. Or you might have luck if you use min-width.

```
a{display:block;}
```

or

```
element.find('.sidebar a').css('min-width','30px');
```

see how that goes...

Comment: stubborn thing won't work; but this finally did, with lots of trial and error : `var side = $('#content > div:nth-child(2) > div');     
                    side.css('width', '30px');`

Comment: in other words, the div which contained the font awesome icon - `fa-arrow-circle-left` - would simply NOT collapse to the left. But somehow `$('content > ...')` ended up working. Now I need to reverse everything back in place...

Comment: you seem to have a class name for all of your divs, does targeting them not work? .divClass{width:30px}. Ive had similar probs in the past where the divs resize but the links dont. So perhaps setting a width for the div rather than the link is the way to go... Seems like you'll have it sorted soon enough though.